# Android multiple screen guide

Tags: android-layout

Iam newbie to android development
Currently iam developing a project but i don't know how to support multiple screen for all devices so can anyone guide me to make my app that compatible for all devices..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no magic stick to support all screen sizes it depends on the `dimens.xml` files with different density e.g: you give some view height and width `100dp` and test this on low and high screen resolution but why dp? `px = dp * (dpi / 160)` from the equation dp is proportion of number of pixels on screen and points per inch physically where `1dp = 160px` as in the 160 points screen and accordingly different phones have different `dpi` denisty points per inch

mdpi -> 1dp=1px

hdmpi -> 1dp=1.5px

xdpi -> 1dp=2px

xxdpi -> 1dp=3px

xxxdpi -> 1dp=4px

so to make statement right and clear you need to set diffrents dps based on screen resoultions to match the proportion of pixels that the dp should have

i use a very beautiful tool on android studio called

> `Dimenify`

search on plugins and install it then restart `android studio`
and use it as:

```
- Navigate to the android studio dimension file
- Point the cursor to any dimen you've create
- Right click > Generate > "Generate alternate dimens.."
```

i prefer the following mapping `mdpi 0.8, hdpi 1.0, xhdpi 1.2, xxhdpi 1.4, xxxhdpi 1.6` adjust as you like

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout).

It's a layout with flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups) - basically, you can creat one layout that will be responsive to all screen sizes.

**From the documentation:**

> ConstraintLayout allows you to create large and complex layouts with a flat view hierarchy (no nested view groups). It's similar to RelativeLayout in that all views are laid out according to relationships between sibling views and the parent layout, but it's more flexible than RelativeLayout and easier to use with Android Studio's Layout Editor.